# Subclipse ignoring files, specially .classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I am unable to ignore .classpath using STS 3.6.3, SVN Team Provider Core 1.10.9. I have seen various answers on SO and I don't see a reason why it doesn't work for me. I want to do it using Windows -> Preferences -> Team -> Ignored Resources, as I find this most generic - if I create/import any projects in future, I wouldn't have to do it again. I have tried following patterns:

1. .classpath (most obvious and should've worked)
2. *.classpath
3. classpath
4. **.classpath
5. **/.classpath
6. .classpath (assuming . is being taken as any single character and ignoring the special meaning)

The .classpath is local - and not in repository.

Answer (score 0):

The `svn:ignore` property is used when checking if some resource is to be added.

If the resource is already in the repository, that check obviously is not performed.

In other words, if the `.classpath` is already in your repository, you will have to remove it first. *Then* it will be ignored.

Comment: It is not in repository - it is auto-generated. I updated the question to reflect that.